Issue with proto object defining isEmpty
we've got this protobuffer object definition (and we cannot modify it)
...
message Condition {
  oneof condition_one_of {
    FieldCondition field = 1;
    IsEmptyCondition is_empty = 2;
    HasIdCondition has_id = 3;
    Filter filter = 4;
    IsNullCondition is_null = 5;
    NestedCondition nested = 6;
  }
}

message IsEmptyCondition {
  string key = 1;
}

message IsNullCondition {
    string key = 1;
}
...

When we run scalaPB tasks we have the following error:
[error] /Users/pippo/qdrant4s/target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main/scalapb/qdrant/points/Condition.scala:210:9: method isEmpty is defined twice;
[error]   the conflicting method isEmpty was defined at line 201:9
[error]     def isEmpty: _root_.scala.Option[qdrant.points.IsEmptyCondition] = _root_.scala.None

Anyway to overcome this?

You provide insufficient information (e.g. line numbers in the error message without corrororation) but, I assume, either IsEmptyCondition was already defined as a field in Condition and you're attempting to replace|override the definition. If true, then you will cause various problems including breaking other messages and  backwards compatibility by revising the definition. If you want to force the change through, you will need to remove other references to IsEmptyCondition so that there's only one definition and know that you're possibly creating bigger problems.

Thanks for you quick reply. Here's the full proto file https://github.com/qdrant/qdrant/blob/master/lib/api/src/grpc/proto/points.proto#L781

(To add more details to those who are not familiary with ScalaPB) Here's how ScalaPB works with oneofs => https://scalapb.github.io/docs/generated-code#oneof-fields

Perhaps https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations/#auxiliary-options

It is not relevant to this issue but the protobuf sources don't follow the convention of using the package structure to represent the folder path. The Protobuf resources are in package qdrant and -- convention -- would want them to be in protos/qdrant too.
